# How to parse slice inside json in golang?

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal json data. The slice inside is deliberately without quotes, because this is what I am getting from https (added manually \ before ")

```
data:="{\"queryEndTime\" : \"2017-11-15T14:39:00Z\", \"message\" : [{\"spamScore\":67,\"phishScore\":0}]}"
```

into Message struct:

```
type Message struct {
    QueryEndTime string `json:"queryEndTime"`
    Message []string `json:"message"`

}
```

but I am getting correct QueryEndTime and empty Message. I tried to change Message type but it always stays empty

```
var message Message
json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &message)
fmt.Printf("QueryEndTime: %s\nMessage: %s\n", message.QueryEndTime, message.Message)
QueryEndTime: 2017-11-15T14:39:00Z
Message: []
```

See it in go playground https://play.golang.org/p/on0_cSKb0c.

Comment: What do you mean the "slice is without quotes"? You have a json array with a single object. That can't unmarshal into a slice of strings.

Comment: message in json is an object, not a string "without quotes".

Comment: If you would be "kind" enough to check error messages (like here on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VZ8hoZbU3Y)), you'll see why it fails: _"json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Message.message of type string"_. Never omit errors.

Comment: Don't use string to unmarshal a JSON object but a struct like `struct{SpamScore int; PhishScor int}` and use the appropriate tags. And please bookmark https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/.

Comment: wow...I love that Volker's mholt.github.io/json-to-go, do you have something like this for xml ? ;)

Comment: @irom you probably meant to say 'JSON array in your data string' is what you getting from your api. Yes?

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Message struct {
    QueryEndTime string `json:"queryEndTime"`

    // you need to use a struct can use anon struct
    Message      []struct {
        SpamScore  int `json:"spamScore"`
        PhishScore int `json:"phishScore"`
    } `json:"message"`

}

func main() {
    var message Message

    // You can use backticks to for your example JSON, so that you don't have to escape anything.
    data := `{
        "queryEndTime" : "2017-11-15T14:39:00Z", 
        "message" : [
            {"spamScore":67, "phishScore":0}
        ]
    }`

    // please check for errors
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &message)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // +v prints structs very nicely 
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", message)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Mu3WZCej3L

Have fun!

Comment: Appreciate a lot, I think Volker was first